# List-view is showing only one data per page

Tags: android, mysql, android-listview

I am loading data in List-view from MySQL database, everything is working fine except that my List-view is showing one data per page if i scroll down then second data if again i scroll down then third data. It is not showing one after another. So what is the problem, Do i need to set any property or anything else. Please help me below is my code.

[image]

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/classes_slider"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/headerbar_small" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/skirrlogo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/skirrwhite" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/skirrmenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/slideropener" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/skirrlogo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/skirrlogo"
    android:text="@string/classses"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/newclass"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/class_button_new" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/deletemenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/skirrlogo"
    android:src="@drawable/menubutton_large" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/displaydata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newclass" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Customclass.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/back_bg" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how i am loading data in List-view:

```
/**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        Classes_Ext_DB.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.custom_class, new String[] {
                                TAG_CLASSNAME, TAG_ID },
                        new int[] { R.id.classname });
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What do you mean by one data? and one data per page? ListView appears to be used in one single page and has multiple rows

Comment: Check your back_bg size , I think, back_bg size is big...

Comment: @AstralProjection, i have added image now if i scroll down then only i am able to see other data, it is not loading other data exact below my first data. it is taking whole activity page for one data.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur, No that is not an issue here...

Comment: @InnocentKiller I agree with Md please remove background then try and tell us the result

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur, sorry for my previous comment it is working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan, Yes MD was right, that Back_bg was big and it was causing issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur, Can you help me in one more issue, in this same activity setOnItemClickListener is not working, i am trying to move to other activity by clicking list-view item but when i press list-view item nothing happen. Can you help me to solve this issue please...

Comment: Post your OnItemClickListener code here and via other StackOverFlow Question.. any one can help you.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur, please check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967000/setonitemclicklistener-is-not-working-in-list-view-android i have posted my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just remove your `android:background="@drawable/back_bg"` from your `Customclass.xml` and everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

custom_class.xml is same as Customclass.xml right?? check and make sure.