# setOnItemClickListener is not working in list-view android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to move to other activity by clicking on list item which is loaded in list-view, but i don't why it is not moving to any other activity when i click on any list item nothing happens no crash, not moving to other activity nothing. Can any-one help me please.

I searched lot and got so many solution but any of the solution is not working in my case. Please help below is my activity code.

```
public class Classes_Ext_DB extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView imageViewNewClass, imageViewDelete;
ListView mListView;

/** Sliding Menu */
boolean alreadyShowing = false;
private int windowWidth;
private Animation animationClasses;
private RelativeLayout classesSlider;
LayoutInflater layoutInflaterClasses;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterSpinner;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_classDetail = "server detail/get_all_classdetail.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_class = "server-detail/delete_class.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
private static final String TAG_CLASSNAME = "class_name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.classes);

    imageViewNewClass = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.newclass);
    imageViewDelete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.deletemenu);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.displaydata);

    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    windowWidth = display.getWidth();
    display.getHeight();
    layoutInflaterClasses = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this,
                    RecordAudio.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });

    new LoadAllClassDetail().execute();

    imageViewNewClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this,
                    Class_Create_Ext_DB.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        }
    });

    imageViewDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Classes_Ext_DB.this);

            final Spinner spinnerDelete = new Spinner(Classes_Ext_DB.this);
            alertDialog.setView(spinnerDelete);

            adapterSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    Classes_Ext_DB.this, R.array.delete_menu,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapterSpinner
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerDelete.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            if (spinnerDelete.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0) {
                                new DeleteProduct().execute();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();

        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.skirrmenu).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!alreadyShowing) {
                alreadyShowing = true;
                openSlidingMenu();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100 then load item by reloading activity again
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

class LoadAllClassDetail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Classes. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_classDetail,
                "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Classes: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String cid = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String cn = c.getString(TAG_CLASSNAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, cid);
                    map.put(TAG_CLASSNAME, cn);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Class_Create_Ext_DB.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        Classes_Ext_DB.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.custom_class, new String[] {
                                TAG_CLASSNAME, TAG_ID },
                        new int[] { R.id.classname });
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                mListView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        });
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Class
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Class... Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ID", TAG_ID));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_delete_class,
                    "POST", params);
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());
            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

private void openSlidingMenu() {
    // showFadePopup();
    int width = (int) (windowWidth * 0.8f);
    translateView((float) (width));
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
    // creating a popup
    final View layout = layoutInflaterClasses.inflate(
            R.layout.option_popup_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));

    ImageView imageViewassignment = (ImageView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.assignment);
    imageViewassignment.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imageViewfacebook = (ImageView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.likefb);
    imageViewfacebook.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imageViewTwitter = (ImageView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.twitter);
    imageViewTwitter.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imageViewBattery = (ImageView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.battery);
    imageViewBattery.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imageViewAudio = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.audio);
    imageViewAudio.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imageViewTakeNotes = (ImageView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.takenote);
    imageViewTakeNotes.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imageViewAllNotes = (ImageView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.allnotes);
    imageViewAllNotes.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imageViewReportBug = (ImageView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.reportbug);
    imageViewReportBug.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView imageViewFeedback = (ImageView) layout
            .findViewById(R.id.feedback);
    imageViewFeedback.setOnClickListener(this);

    final PopupWindow optionsPopup = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height,
            true);
    optionsPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new PaintDrawable());
    optionsPopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
    optionsPopup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss() {
            // to clear the previous animation transition in
            cleanUp();
            // move the view out
            translateView(0);
            // to clear the latest animation transition out
            cleanUp();
            // resetting the variable
            alreadyShowing = false;
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.assignment:
        Intent assign = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this, Assignment.class);
        startActivity(assign);
        break;

    case R.id.likefb:
        Intent facebook = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this,
                FacebookLogin.class);
        startActivity(facebook);
        break;

    case R.id.facebooklogin:
        Intent twitter = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this, TwitterLogin.class);
        startActivity(twitter);
        break;

    case R.id.battery:
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialogBattery = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        myDialogBattery.setTitle("How to use Less Battery");

        TextView textViewBattery = new TextView(Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        ImageView imageViewBattery = new ImageView(Classes_Ext_DB.this);

        imageViewBattery.setImageResource(R.drawable.batteryicon);
        textViewBattery
                .setText("The best way to use less amount of battery possible is to lower the brightness level on your device");
        textViewBattery.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        textViewBattery.setTextSize(20);
        LayoutParams textViewLayoutParamsBattery = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textViewBattery.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParamsBattery);

        LinearLayout layoutBattery = new LinearLayout(Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        layoutBattery.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layoutBattery.addView(textViewBattery);
        layoutBattery.addView(imageViewBattery);

        myDialogBattery.setView(layoutBattery);
        myDialogBattery.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    // do something when the button is clicked
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    }
                });
        myDialogBattery.show();
        break;

    case R.id.audio:
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialogAudio = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        myDialogAudio.setTitle("How to get better audio notes");

        TextView textViewAudio = new TextView(Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        ImageView imageViewAudio = new ImageView(Classes_Ext_DB.this);

        imageViewAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.micicon);
        textViewAudio
                .setText("Getting the best sounding audio is important, to make sure you are getting the best audio notes possible always ensure that the microphone is facing the speakes.");
        textViewAudio.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        textViewAudio.setTextSize(20);
        LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textViewAudio.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);

        LinearLayout layoutAudio = new LinearLayout(Classes_Ext_DB.this);
        layoutAudio.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layoutAudio.addView(textViewAudio);
        layoutAudio.addView(imageViewAudio);

        myDialogAudio.setView(layoutAudio);

        myDialogAudio.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    }
                });
        myDialogAudio.show();
        break;

    case R.id.takenote:
        Intent takenote = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this,
                Classes_Ext_DB.class);
        startActivity(takenote);
        break;

    case R.id.allnotes:
        Intent allNotes = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this, RecordAudio.class);
        startActivity(allNotes);
        break;

    case R.id.reportbug:
        Intent reportBug = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this, ReportBug.class);
        startActivity(reportBug);
        break;

    case R.id.feedback:
        Intent feedback = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this, Feedback.class);
        startActivity(feedback);
        break;
    }
}

private void translateView(float right) {
    animationClasses = new TranslateAnimation(0f, right, 0f, 0f);
    animationClasses.setDuration(100);
    animationClasses.setFillEnabled(true);
    animationClasses.setFillAfter(true);

    classesSlider = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.classes_slider);
    classesSlider.startAnimation(animationClasses);
    classesSlider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void cleanUp() {
    if (null != classesSlider) {
        classesSlider.clearAnimation();
        classesSlider = null;
    }
    if (null != animationClasses) {
        animationClasses.cancel();
        animationClasses = null;
    }
}
}
```

**Edit**

`MyXML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/classes_slider"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/headerbar_small" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/skirrlogo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/skirrwhite" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/skirrmenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/slideropener" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/skirrlogo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/skirrlogo"
    android:text="@string/classses"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/newclass"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/class_button_new" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/deletemenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/skirrlogo"
    android:src="@drawable/menubutton_large" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/displaydata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newclass" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_class.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/classname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, i am not getting any error...

Comment: Please Can you remove it :: implements OnClickListener , if you do not need this...

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur, how can i implement OnClickListener for list-item.

Comment: Try `Intent mIntent = new Intent(item.getContext(), RecordAudio.class);`

Comment: @InnocentKiller post the xml layout and where do you set adapter to listview?

Comment: @Innocent Killer, IF it is your full activity code then do not need to implements OnClickListener and your mListView.setOnItemClickListener is ok...

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur, No this is not my full activity code.

Comment: @InnocentKiller  can you post the custom layout inlfated for listivew?

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur, i have updated my full code.

Comment: @Raghunandan, no i don't have custom adapter. i have updated my full code. And i have added android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" this to my list-view but nothing happen.

Comment: @InnocentKiller that should be for the root element  in `custom_class.xml`

Comment: @Raghunandan, i have updated my all XML and java code. please have a look.

Comment: @Raghunandan, but i don't have a list-view in custom class, i just have check-box and text-view

Comment: @InnocentKiller probaly checkbox is taking focus when you click on listitem add that to the root element and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Android doesn't allow you to select list items that have elements on them that are focusable. I modified the checkbox on the list item to have an attribute like so:

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Now my list items that contain checkboxes (works for buttons too) are "selectable" in the traditional sense (they light up, you can click anywhere in the list item and the "onListItemClick" handler will fire, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Add this

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants
```

to the root element in `custom_class.xml`

Probably checkbox takes focus when you click on list item. So just add the above to the root element in xml.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability

`android:descendantFocusability`

Defines the relationship between the ViewGroup and its descendants when looking for a View to take focus.

Must be one of the following constant values.

```
Constant          Value   Description
beforeDescendants   0      The ViewGroup will get focus before any of its descendants.
afterDescendants    1      The ViewGroup will get focus only if none of its descendants want it.
blocksDescendants   2      The ViewGroup will block its descendants from receiving focus.
This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol descendantFocusability.
```

You can also add

```
 android:focusable= "false"
```

for the checkbox

`android:focusable`

Boolean that controls whether a view can take focus. By default the user can not move focus to a view; by setting this attribute to true the view is allowed to take focus. This value does not impact the behavior of directly calling requestFocus(), which will always request focus regardless of this view. It only impacts where focus navigation will try to move focus.

Must be a boolean value, either "true" or "false".

Comment: @InnocentKiller to the root element in your xml

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:focusable=false` in checkbox of custom_class.xml

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

to

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
```

Comment: `OnItemClickListener` and `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` are the same.

Comment: Try `Intent mIntent = new Intent(item.getContext(),  RecordAudio.class);`

Comment: @ling.s, Intent mIntent = new Intent(item.getContext(), RecordAudio.class); with this also, not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
mListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(Classes_Ext_DB.this,
                    RecordAudio.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried android:focusable="false" on the checkbox ?